# Xcode Archives is empty even after successful Archives

Tags: ios, xcode

Actually I installed Xcode Server, after that even If I have stoppped it , my Archives are not generating... After Successful build also Archicves is showing empty.

Please see the error image below
[image: See the image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the path is set correctly for the Archives

[image]

[image]

If all okay then check whether you have installed more than one Xcode 
Then set the path. Also check that necessary apple account is there